# Why do we need to set the Content-Type header of an HTTP request?

Tags: web, httpwebrequest, content-type, request-headers, webresponse

I have the following questions:

- What is the content type?
- Why do we need to set the content type header of an HTTP request?
- How many types of header content can be set?

Please provide documentation if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Content-Type` in the header of a HTTP request specifies to the server what data it should expect. If a server allows and accepts multiple types of content it can use this field know how to interpret the body of the request.

For example: If a server allows both XML and JSON data at the same endpoint, then setting the `Content-Type` as:

> Content-Type: application/json

would let the server know it should expect the request body to contain JSON. Whereas passing:

> Content-Type: text/xml

would inform the server to expect XML in the body.

[RFC7321 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) defines `Content-Type` in section [3.1.1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5):

> The "Content-Type" header field indicates the media type of the
> associated representation: either the representation enclosed in the
> message payload or the selected representation, as determined by the
> message semantics.  The indicated media type defines both the data
> format and how that data is intended to be processed by a recipient,
> within the scope of the received message semantics, after any content
> codings indicated by Content-Encoding are decoded.

There are 1500+ [Media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) registered with the [IANA](https://www.iana.org/) which can be set as the `Content-Type` for a request.

The last paragraph of section 3.1.1.5 explains that if `Content-Type` is not set, the server may assume the data is `application/octet-stream` or interpret the request any way it wants. But:

> Clients that do
> so risk drawing incorrect conclusions, which might expose additional
> security risks (e.g., "privilege escalation").

It is called [Content Sniffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_sniffing) when a server does this and may be disabled by setting:

> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Comment: brother IANA stands for?

Comment: if we don't set any content-type then what problem can occur

Comment: IANA stand for the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority. They maintain the IP allotments, Port numbers, and are the global coordinators of DNS Top-Level Domains.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a link to IANA, and explain what can happen if Content-Type is not set.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not set Content-Type your app may not work.

For example if you are building an app that expects data in json format and you do not include `Content-Type: application/json` in your header then in most of the cases your app will malfunction.